# not your average Cannot open include file: 'D3DX10.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directx

Before you try to link me to some other question, please read everything. I am getting this error but I have everything set up correctly. It's not my first time with c++. i am a moderate user and have never had this issue before nor am I having it with any of my other projects.

I'll start off my saying that the file, "D3DX10.h", does exist in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include".

The "DXSDK_DIR" system variable points to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\".

My Include Directories for the project for all configurations includes "$(DXSDK_DIR)Include".

Now when I try `#include <D3DX10.h>`, I get "error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'D3DX10.h': No such file or directory" but when i try '#include "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include/D3DX10.h"', it does infact build and runs with no errors.

Has anyone ran accross this issue and is there anyway to fix it?

Again, please keep in mind that i have other projects that get "D3DX10.h" using the system variable. That is not the issue here.

Comment: Use double quotes instead of angle brackets, `#include "d3dx10.h"`

Comment: "I have everything set up correctly." --- It follows that everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ha! I got it! It's the parent project that needs to also have the environment variables defined most likely because my library uses some variables directly from D3DX10.h.